# Show that matrix $[A, B; B^T, C]$ is nonsingular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

For homework at my uni we have the following problem:

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ all be $n\times n$ matrices. Suppose $C$ and $A-BC^{-1}B^T$ are both nonsingular. Show that matrix $[A B; B^T C]$ is nonsingular and find its inverse.

Now I know when a matrix is nonsingular or not. But with this problem I don't know where or how to start, I have tried many things but all of them failed. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking at is the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Schur_complement_condition_for_positive_definiteness_and_positive_semidefiniteness) of $C$ in your block matrix $M$.  See the wiki page for a formula for the inverse.

The idea here is to apply block-matrix row-reduction.

Comment: I see now that this is the schur complement, but I have no idea how block-matrix row-reduction works nor how to show that this matrix is nonsingular or its inverse.

Comment: Take a look at the article, then, and see if that makes sense to you.

Comment: After reading that article and reading some stuff about block-matrix inversion I think I know how to solve this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.  Once you're confident that you've arrived at a solution, I'd appreciate it if you could accept this answer (by clicking the $\checkmark$).